# RewriteCond in .htaccess with exact match condition doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a scenario where on exact match of requested host, i want to redirect into one url and in case of parameters with requested url, i want to redirect into different url.

```
RewriteEngine On    
    
# redirection test for Host
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =^abc-dev\.cco\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://xyz.sp.com/sites/SitePages/abc-migration.aspx [R=301,L]

# Redirect Test for estore curt dev
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc-dev\.cco\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://xyz-curt-dev.cco.com/redir/xyz?u=%{REQUEST_URI}&h=abc-dev.cco.com [R=301,L]
```

Test case:

1. Url requested: abc-dev.cco.com
   Target redirection Url: https://xyz.sp.com/sites/SitePages/abc-migration.aspx
2. Url requested: abc-dev.cco.com/test123
   Target redirection Url: https://xyz-curt-dev.cco.com/redir/xyz?u=/test123&h=abc-dev.cco.com

With the above mentioned rule, It's not happening. Any idea what is the mistake here? Many thanks in advance..!

Was testing here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com

Comment: `=` in a RewriteCond is for lexicographical string comparison, should not be in there when you are using a regular expressions. You are testing against REQUEST_URI in the first part, which should be HTTP_HOST. And the distinction between empty URL path or not, you have not implemented at all yet.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response. I am beginner in Apache world.  I tried with HTTP_HOST as well but it's not working. On distinction between host url vs host url with param/path variable. I am relying on order of rule and [L] so that if satisfied, the next condition won't run. 

You can see here
Working:
https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=38ece0dc-2ec9-40c7-86a4-ee712ee91bba

Not working:
https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=629217c2-6560-40bd-a488-b58425d5decb

Thanks

Comment: Like I said, regarding the `=` and use of a regular expression: `=^abc-dev\.cco\.com` should be just `^abc-dev\.cco\.com`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I used ^abc-dev\.cco\.com and exact Host is working but the next test case is failing where host/path variable/ is requested and i want to redirect to different url as mentioned in examples..

Comment: So match only on an empty path with your first RewriteRule then. `^$`